# Android WebView canGoBack always returns false

Tags: java, android, google-chrome, webview

Steps to reproduce the problem:

1. Create a fragment with a WebView inside.
2. Navigate a few sites deep in the WebView building a history.
3. Try using webview.canGoBack() function.
4. Observe it always returns false.

This is a new behavior, since WebView did return true before.

It seems that a new version of the WebView has broken this functionality.

Here's my code:

```
class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        // Loads all hyperlinks in the existing WebView
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            // Protection against getActivity() returning null object reference
            if (!isAdded()) return true;

            // Allow WebView to load url
            Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
            // Google Maps
            if (url.contains("maps.google")) {
                Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
                mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
                if (mapIntent.resolveActivity(getActivity().getPackageManager()) != null) {
                    startActivity(mapIntent);
                }
                return true;
            }
            // Telephone
            else if (url.contains("tel:")) {
                String phoneNumber = url.substring(4);
                Utils.dialPhone(getActivity(), phoneNumber);

                return true;
            }

            // Redirect
            return false;
        }
}
```

Here's where I use the goBack API:

```
public boolean canWebViewGoBack() {
    if (mWebView != null) {
        if (mWebView.canGoBack()) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

public void webViewGoBack() {
    if (mWebView != null) {
        if (mWebView.canGoBack()) {
            mWebView.goBack();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Or it is a website ...

Comment: Yes, you are right as It seems that a new version of the WebView has broken this functionality. Same here.

Answer (score 0):

Here [link](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=794020)

talk about the problem and possible solutions

Comment: The only solution in this link is to wait until next Chrome release (65).

Answer (score 0):

WebView canGoBack function is working again after latest Chrome release:

**64.0.3282.137**